# Prove $\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-t} dt = n!$ by differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral, gamma-function

I have to prove $\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-t} dt = n!$  by differentiating infinitely often under the integral. $(t, x > 0)$

I think I have proven that I can make use of a Lemma we have. It is differentiation under the integral sign [(see here)](https://brilliant.org/wiki/differentiate-through-the-integral/). I'm not entirely sure about that because in the Lemma it states that we need to have $x \in I$ where $I$ is an open interval.

In this case we would have $I = (0,\infty)$, which is open, but I'm not sure if this is an interval in that sense.
So I have checked the proof if we made use of some bounds $a, b$, but I couldn't find that, so I presumed that it's allowed. (And also if it's not allowed, couldn't we just use limits then and still get the same results as below?)

However, if I apply that Lemma on $\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}dt = \frac{1}{x}$, then I get:

$$-\frac{1}{x^2} = \int_0^\infty -t e^{-xt}dt$$

Again apply it:

$$\frac{2}{x^3} = \int_0^\infty t^2 e^{-xt} dt$$

Doing it iteratively will lead to:

$$\frac{n!}{x^{n+1}} = \int_0^\infty t^n e^{-xt}dt $$(depending on if $n$ is even, I might need to add a minus at two points, but it's on both sides, so no difference)

But this is not what I needed. I can multiply with $x^{n+1}$ and take it inside the integral:

$$n! = \int_0^\infty t^n \cdot e^{-t} \cdot \frac{x^{n+1}}{e^x}dt$$

This holds for any $x$. So I can choose $x$ that way, that $\frac{x^{n+1}}{e^x} = 1$, such $x$ do exist.

But is this really how it should be done?

Comment: How did $\mathrm e^{-xt}$ become $\frac{\mathrm e^{-t}}{\mathrm e^x}$?

Comment: Remember that $\int_0^{\infty}= \lim \int_0^N$ as $N \to \infty$, and you've proved you can differentiate under the integral sign on the open interval.  Do that, and then take the limit.

Comment: $e^{-xt} \neq \frac{e^{-t}}{e^x}$. Instead, make the change of integration variables from $t$ to $s$ via $s=xt$.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I solved it with this. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Btw, the part "by diffentiating infinitely often under the integral" in your first sentence is incorrect. You have to differentiate $n$ times only.

Comment: But $n$ can be any number, so this needs an inductive argument. This is what I meant with infinetely often

Comment: I understand what you like to say, but it is is still incorrect. To get the formula for $n!$ you have to differentiate $n$ times. Try differentiating it infinitely many times. What do you get? Does it make sense?